# My C# program doesn't go to complete URLs, but instead chops of bits of it towards the end

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm making a program that opens up a random lightshot screenshot using selenium, but when it runs it does not go to the correctly generated URL (I tested it by printing those URLs to my console)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{     
    IWebDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();

    Restart:    
        chromeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URLRandomizer());
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        goto Restart;

    }

    static string URLRandomizer()
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        string linkPart = "https://prnt.sc/";
        string URL;

        char[] allLetters =  { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
        'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'X'};

        URL = linkPart + allLetters[random.Next(0, allLetters.Length)].ToString() + allLetters[random.Next(0, allLetters.Length)].ToString() + random.Next(0, 10).ToString() + random.Next(0, 10).ToString() + random.Next(0, 10).ToString() + random.Next(0, 10).ToString();
        return URL;
    }
}
```

Comment: "I tested it by printing those URLs to my console" - so what do you see in the console and how does it differ?

Comment: I didn't know people still use `goto`. I would advice you to get rid of that habit and use a loop instead (in this example). In far most cases `goto` makes the code harder to read/understand.

Comment: Are you sure your generated URLs are valid? Have you tried taking your output and manually going to the address?

Comment: @Xerillio I've seen it often when people have learned lower level languages and then move on to learning higher level languages. Have had a few friends I was teaching default to `goto` statements because of that, but I was eventually able to get them to understand how methods/functions/loops are abstractions on top of it to make it easier for the developers to read.

Comment: @Ibrennan208 I'm sure those URLs are valid, I printed them to console and then manually entered them into chrome

Comment: @Xerillio so basically the URL when printed to the console was nice and worked when pasted straight to chrome, but when selenium tried to navigate to it the last 5 or 6 letters/numbers were missing in the URL

Comment: Are you able to see the URL that selenium is actually trying to navigate to? When testing by just printing the value to console, were you directly printing `URLRandomizer()` or were you trying to print within the `URLRandomizer` method?

Comment: @Ibrennan208 I created a new variable url in the main method and assigned URLRandomizer to it, then I just put the url variable into Console.WriteLine and GoToUrl()

Comment: @ArnasBies I'm not able to reproduce what you describe. Using your code, the Chrome browser correctly navigates to the URL (with 6 characters following the `/`). If it happens to be a valid/existing URL the page shows an image. If not, the browser redirects to the home page `https://prnt.sc`

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with the URLRandomizer, if it generated a URL with capital letters it redirected to the main site, so the fix was just to delete the capital letters from the allLetters array. Appreciate the feedback for goto statements though, I thought they were fine